# How to find subset of enum in Java?

Tags: java, enums

I have a enum as shown below:

```
public enum DatacenterEnum {
    ABC, PQR, LTR;

    // this tells my current local datacenter enum
    private static final DatacenterEnum ourLocation = findCurrentLocation();

}
```

Now I want to find list of remote datacenters. As an example, let's say if `ourLocation` is ABC, then REMOTE_DATACENTER list or it can be EnumSet (I will be iterating this later on) should have PQR and LTR, similarly for other combinations. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want the *complement*.

```
// contains all DatacenterEnum except ourLocation
Set<DatacenterEnum> remoteSet =
    EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(ourLocation));
// as a List, if you want
List<DataceterEnum> remoteList =
    new ArrayList<>(remoteSet);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works fine. Learned something new today. I have a similar question posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155156/how-to-populate-local-and-remote-list-basis-on-where-the-code-is-running) which is using the same logic. See if you can help me out.

Comment: Well this can be generalized to other things, like `List<DatacenterEnum> others = new ArrayList<>(EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(this))); return others.get(random.nextInt(others.size())).getLocalString();` Hope that helps.